# ggplot2 (R): Error msg: 'Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1093): x, y'

Tags: r, ggplot2

I started learning to use R two days ago, so this is probably a really easy fix!

I started by making this very simple table, showing the %ages of 'g' and 't' in my data (I'm working in socio-linguistics).

```
    ---g---  | ---t--- 
    0.936871 | 0.063129
```

I'm trying to turn this into a bar graph using ggplot2. I want the x-axis to have two categories, with one bar representing 'g' and one representing 't', side by side rather than stacked. I want the y-axis to show the two %ages.

I've tried various different scripts but I keep getting the error message 'Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as in the data'. 
What does this error message mean and how can I fix it?

Thanks!
Sadie

Comment: Try posting the code that produces the error: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you don't have your dataset in the right form.  With your data you've a `t` variable and `g` variable. `ggplot` wants to receive aes values that depict all the elements of that axis/feature.

The data that you have is in wide format (many columns).  `ggplot2` utilizes long format data (key-value pairs) better.  To transform your wide data to long data you use the `tidyr` package (specifically the `gather` function) to gather values into a column of variables and a column of values.  In your case the variables would be g and t and the values would be your percentages.

You'd then pass that transformed data into `ggplot`, specifying the x-axis as the variable, the y-axis as the percentage.  You want to plot it as a bar with `geom_bar()` setting `stat = "identity"` because you're supplying the values.  The last step is setting the labels on the y-axis to percent via `scale_y_continuous`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(g = 0.936871,
                 t = 0.063129)

df <- gather(df, variable, value)

ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As to your comment request:

```
df <- data.frame(
  category = c(1, 2),
  g = c(0.8070175, 0.97099768),
  t = c(0.1929825, 0.029000232)
)

df <- gather(df, variable, value, -category)

ggplot(df, aes(x = category, y = value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = variable), position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c(1,2), breaks = c(1,2), labels = c("Category 1", "Category 2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much, this is really helpful! What about if I wanted to compare g and t percentages for two or more categories on the same graph? So I have these results: In category 1, g = 0.8070175, t = 0.1929825. In category 2, g = 0.97099768, t = 0.029000232. How would I go about asking ggplot to show me those results in a graph?

Comment: Edited my answer.  You should search online for some ggplot2 tutorials.  There are a lot of good ones to help teach you the basics.